# Detect assembly change on Asp.Net application

Tags: asp.net

I have an Asp.Net Web API 2 app with some files embedded into an assembly. When one of this files is requested I create an object based on it's content and save this object on server memory (this objects has a cost to be created and has a high access frequency but are small in terms of memory).

However every time I use this cached version I need to check the version of the assembly where the original file is embedded to recreate the cached element if necessary.

Is there an alternative to this approach that avoids the assembly version reading?

Comment: Could you show some code?

Comment: If assembly change causes application pool recycle you can safely avoid version checking and serve only last created object. If not, I would use `MemoryCache` and `FileChangeMonitor` from `System.Runtime.Checking` to watch for assembly file's changes.